# Server executes more threads than specified

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, java-server

I'm creating server that execute some queries. Max number of threads is set with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)` but when I run 3 clients all of them are connected to that server at the same time. It is important to have only 2 threads active at the same time. Any ideas whats wrong? There is part of server code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
ExecutorService server = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
while (true) {
     Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
     Query query = new Query(clientSocket, allLogs);
     server.submit(query);
}
```

When I run 3 clients first got answer: `Server response: pool-1-thread-1`, second `Server response: pool-1-thread-2` and third `Server response: pool-1-thread-1`. As far as I know third thread should go in queue and wait until one is done.

Comment: What does your Query implementation do? Maybe it exits with an error after sending the first response?

Comment: third Server response: `pool-1-thread-1`. 3rd task execute by first thread

Comment: When `pool-#-thread-#` is the name of the thread, everything is working as you expected it: the third client gets served after the work for the first client was done …

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because thread works as expected

Comment: The `server.submit(query)` call does not wait until a worker thread is available to handle the `query`. It just puts the `query` in a queue and immediately returns.  You can have lots of clients _connected_ at the same time, but only two of them will be able to interact with the service _after_ they have been connected.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when a ThreadPoolExecutor is configured with CallerRunsPolicy, which means when they queue is full the task is executed on the calling thread.